# Add a list of information into a tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I currently have a grid which has tooltips so that when a number is hovered over, a tooltip is displayed with some text.

I have created the tooltip by setting the title of a `<a>` tag.
Within my tooltip, however, I want to display a list of information relating to the number within the tooltip.

How would I go about doing this? I tried looping through the array within the title tag with no success (If that worked I would have been surprised).

Code:

```
@{var grid = new WebGrid(Model.ModelName, canSort: false); }

            <hr />
            <div class="panel panel-default pre-scrollable">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>header1</th>
                            <th>header2</th>
                            <th>header3</th>
                            <th>header4</th>
                            <th>header5</th>
                            <th>header6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ModelName)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.SomeValue1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.SomeValue2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.SomeValue3
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (@item.Response.Item1 != 0)

                                {
                                @*Print the items in list into tooltip*@
                                <a title= @foreach (string name in item.List) { name.ToString() } >@item.Response.Item1</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @item.Response.Item1
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.Response.Item2
                            </td>s
                            <td>
                                @item.Response.Item3
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: A tooltip made by using `title=` can only be plain text.  It is also controlled by the browser - so you can't style or position it or even determine how long it is shown for; IE in particular hides these tooltips after about 20s (or at least used to) and you have to move off and show another one to get it back.   Use a tooltip plugin (quick google for jquery tooltip plugin) or, as you've tagged this bootstrap, just use the bootstrap one!  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: After code added: Well, you *can* do it that way - just add quotes and an @ sign: `<a title='@foreach (string name in item.List) { @name.ToString() + " " }' >`

Comment: Hi freedomn, thanks but the same thing happens with this suggestion, the tooltip doesn't appear. 
I was only using title as I didn't know another way around it. I had a look at the bootstrap link you sent but this also seems to use the title to display the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I didn't post a solution to this problem.
Eventually I solved it using razor syntax to loop through each user within the list and append new lines with the next users name to a string on each iteration. This is then printed in the cells title.

```
@*Initialise a new string for each table row*@
@{string sDeclined = null;}

@*Loop through each user in list*@
@foreach (var user in item.DeclinedList)
{
     @*Append a new line and the current user to the string of users*@
     sDeclined = sDeclined + "\n" + user;
}

@*Set the title as the string of users*@
<td title="@sDeclined">
     @item.Response.Item2
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a title="@String.Join("\n", item.List.ToArray())">@item.Response.Item1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks that can accomplish a more robust tooltip. Jquery have a very simple one which can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tooltip</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).tooltip(
        {
        content:function(){return $(this).attr('title');},
    }
    );
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body> 

<p>
    <a href="#" title="Here is a list<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>">Here</a> is a tooltip that conatins a list
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x5uw4cfy/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the anchor tag you suggested but it doesn't compile as valid html. The html list tags don't seem to get included within the string.

Comment: Does the JSFiddle not work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/x5uw4cfy/ When you say doesn't compile. Do you mean it doesn't validate against a validator?

Comment: Ah sorry, because you didn't originally include the razor syntax I assumed this was a front end html question. Sorry for the confusion.